# TabTransformer Multiclass classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tabular, transformer-model

TabTransformer: Is there any documentation or example implementation of multiclass tabular data classifiation using TabTransformer in Tensorflow?

Following reference from keras is for binary classification only:
https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/tabtransformer/

And converting the sigmoid to softmax and increasing the output layer nodes to C(total classes) comes out with errors.